# Angular date parsing unexpected output

Tags: angularjs, date, format

I'm trying to display a date using the `date` action, but it's giving odd output.

```
{{ mydate | date:'mm/dd/yyyy' }}
```

The month seems to be inconsistent and incorrect. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `MM` to display the month:

```
{{ mydate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
'MM': Month in year, padded (01-12)
...
'mm': Minute in hour, padded (00-59)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `date:'MM/dd/yyy'`

`mm` is for minutes, `MM` is for months